# Highlight a button based on existence of a cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cookies

I have several buttons on my site as well as several cookies. I have a cookie named "chosenValue" and I want to highlight the value corresponding to the to the value stored in the cookie. For example, I retrieve the value stored in the cookie:

```
var value = readCookie('chosenValue');
```

Say the value stored is "id1." Then, I want to highlight the button associated with "id1."

```
<input type="button" class="buttons" name="button-terms" value="id1"></input>
<input type="button" class="buttons" name="button-terms" value="id2"></input>
<input type="button" class="buttons" name="button-terms" value="id3"></input></h3>
```

Currently the buttons highlight based on hover. But I want it to highlight based on the value stored in the cookie.

```
/*Button stylings */
.buttons {
    border: solid;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px
    font-size: 120%;
    background: transparent;
    margin-top: 20px;
    color: black;
    border-color: black;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: "brandon-grotesque",sans-serif;
}

.buttons:hover {
    background: darkred;
    border-color: black;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Give them a id that corresponds to the value. Then get the Element by `document.getElementById(readCookie('chosenValue')' and then you can use attribute `.className`for the element.

Comment: Will the value of this cookie get changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change ".buttons:hover" to ".buttons:hover, .button-active" in your CSS, then in your javascript:

```
$(".buttons[value="+readCookie('chosenValue')+"]").addClass("button-active");
```

Answer (score -1):

Try :

JS:

```
document.getElementById(readCookie('chosenValue')).className = 'buttons highlighted';
```

CSS:

```
.buttons.highlighted { background: orange }
```